# How can I make better display board using python

Tags: python, ubuntu, browser, pyqt

I am beginner in python and stackoverflow

I am going to make a better desplay using python. I have a ubuntu on beaglebord. I want to make a good display(It only desplays some datas interactively - It gives some output only, no input gui interaction is provided) using python.  I here about pyqt. But I don't know is it ok to design a better dashboard in my case. Is it possible to connect with a minimal browser(like what do in ATM's) desplay using python. So that I can design it using HTML and CSS.

please help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This forum is for answering specific questions, not for general guidance.  Also, people are more likely to help when they see that you have tried something already.  I am guessing this is why your question has been downvoted.  I recommend asking a specific question, and also be more descriptive in the question (i.e. better display that what?  What does the display do?  What is the project for?), and also show some example code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can design your UI using HTML and CSS. You must use pyQT's QWebView control to display these html pages as below

```
    dashboard = QWebView()
    dashboard.load("dashboard.html")
    dashboard.show()
```